# Parse CSV File to Find Distinct Columns in Python

Tags: python-2.7, group-by, python-itertools

I have a ~3000 line CSV file formatted with the following column headers:

```
STORE|BRAND ID|ZONE|SHORT DESCRIPTION (ZONE)|REGION|SHORT DESCRIPTION (REGION)|DISTRICT|SHORT DESCRIPTION (DISTRICT)
```

Here is a sample of that data:

```
0010|Company A|0001|East|123|New England|012|Connecticut
0010|Company B|0002|West|456|Coast|010|Oregon
0025|Company A|0001|East|246|South|010|Florida
0010|Company A|0004|West|456|Coast|011|California
```

There are duplicate zones, regions and districts within the file. What I'm trying to accomplish is aggregate the data by ZONE, REGION and DISTRICT per BRAND like this:

**:ZONES:**

```
0001|Company A|East
0002|Company B|West
0004|Company A|West
```

**:REGIONS:**

```
123|Company A|New England
456|Company B|Coast
246|Company A|South
```

**:DISTRICTS:**

```
012|Company A|Connecticut
010|Company A|Oregon
010|Company B|Florida
011|Company A|California
```

The code below, leveraging itertools/groupby, works fine and provides me the data as I need it, however it bothers me how iterative it is in the sense that I read the file, find distinct zones, read the file again, find distinct regions, read the file a third time and find distinct districts. I'm thinking there has to be a more streamlined approach to reading this file and aggregating this data.

```
with file(myFile, 'r') as f:
        content = f.read()

csv.register_dialect('piper', delimiter='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)

with open(myFile) as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper')

        zones_dict = sorted(list(reader), key=itemgetter('ZONE','SHORT DESCRIPTION (ZONE)','BRAND ID'))     

        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper')

        regions_dict = sorted(list(reader), key=itemgetter('REGION', 'SHORT DESCRIPTION (REGION)', 'BRAND ID', 'ZONE'))

        csvfile.seek(0)
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, dialect='piper')

        districts_dict = sorted(list(reader), key=itemgetter('DISTRICT', 'SHORT DESCRIPTION (DISTRICT)', 'BRAND ID', 'REGION'))

        ###
        #Aggregate Zone#
        ###

        for zone_id, zone_group in groupby(zones_dict, itemgetter('ZONE','SHORT DESCRIPTION (ZONE)','BRAND ID')):
            theZone = zone_id
            print theZone[0]

        print " "

        ###
        #Aggregate Region#
        ###

        for region_id, region_group in groupby(regions_dict, itemgetter('REGION', 'SHORT DESCRIPTION (REGION)', 'BRAND ID', 'ZONE')):
            theRegion = region_id
            print theRegion[0]

        print " "

        ###
        #Aggregate District#
        ###

        for district_id, district_group in groupby(districts_dict, itemgetter('DISTRICT', 'SHORT DESCRIPTION (DISTRICT)', 'BRAND ID', 'REGION')):
            theDistrict = district_id
            print theDistrict[0]
```

Any thoughts on a better approach?

Comment: This sounds like the kind of thing databases are made for. Can you insert your CSV file into a db and query it for the results?

Comment: Try looking at [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org). A `DataFrame` is exactly what you need here.

Comment: If importing this data into a db were in scope for what I've been tasked with it would have been done already and I'd have more hair left ;) I do appreciate the suggestion though :)

Comment: I was thinking something along the lines of sqlite. https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html I haven't actually used it before, so I could be talking out my behind, but as I understand, you don't need to have access to a db server to use it. But if a db is out, then a db is out :(